# How do I add unallocated space to my distro?

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, gparted

[image]

I deleted my old main distro, and now I have unallocated space i want to add to the new one but gparted doesn't let me resize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to boot with Ubuntu or Lubuntu LiveUSB and do it from there.

After you boot from LiveUSB first disable swap by right-clicking it in gparted or run

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

in terminal.

Then extend `sda2` left, then extend `sda6` left.

You will also need to update grub, because the starting point ot the boot partition will change. Run in terminal.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
exit
```

Then you will be able to boot normally.

Comment: I tried using gparted from my liveDVD and still coudn't add the space, I don't know if it was this that you meant.

Comment: Oh, forgot to add one thing. Your swap does not let to move the extended partition.

Comment: How can i do it then?

Comment: See the updated answer. Disable swap, then it will let you do the rest.

Comment: @Rockloh But the process of extending the partition will take a lot of time, so be patient.

Comment: The options are still locked the only one i can change is /dev/sda2 what should i do?

Comment: Can you read the answer again? It contains everything. First extend sda2, other partitions are inside of it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think i did it now. I was exausted from doing this all night, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for software called "Disks" and open it.

If you don't have this software, you can install this software by searching for "gnome-disk-utility" in synaptic package manager or Ubuntu software center.

2. Identify the unallocated space.
3. Format it as ext4 and use it.